# How to ignore first symbol in .append method?

Tags: java

I found problem which I don't know how to solve, so I need your help. Code example:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    Integer x = -239;
    char[] y = String.valueOf(x).toCharArray();
    for(int i = 0; i < y.length; i++){
        builder.append(y[i]);
        System.out.println(builder);
    }
```

And problem with outPut. I see something like that : - -2 -23 -239, but I need to have output without first symbol which is -

Comment: `for(int i = 1; i < y.length; i++)`

Comment: it doesn't work because I need to separate negative values, with int i = 1, it separate but make values positive

Comment: Okay. Then don't do the printing if `i` is 0.

Comment: if (y[0] != '-') {builder.append(i[0]); Then as @radovix.

Answer (score 0):

Simply start to iterate over the array beginning with the second index.

Your for loop starts with `i` at 0 and therefore starts on the first index of the char array.
Assign 1 to `i` in the for-loop and you will iterate over the whole array without the first character.

```
for(int i = 1; i < y.length; i++){
    builder.append(y[i]);
    System.out.println(builder);
}
```